# Java: Getting resource path of the main app instead of jar's

Tags: java

A lot has been discussed already here about getting a resource. 
 If there is already a solution - please point me to it because I couldn't find.

I have a program which uses several jars.
 To one of the jars I added a properties file under main/resources folder.

I've added the following method to the jar project in order to to read it:

```
public void loadAppPropertiesFile() {

    try {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        String resourcePath = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath();
        InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream(resourcePath +  "\\entities.properties");
        prop.load(stream);
        String default_ssl = prop.getProperty("default_ssl");
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

The problem (?) is that resourcePath gives me a path to the target\test-clasess but under the calling application directory although the loading code exists in the jar!

This the jar content:

[image]

The jar is added to the main project by maven dependency.

How can I overcome this state and read the jar resource file?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using the context classloader rather than the class's classloader? I'd expect just `getClass().getResourceAsStream("entities.properties")` to work.

Comment: @JonSkeet Tried this and it returned null. I will add in few seconds an image of the jar content which might be helpful to understand the situation

Comment: Ah, if `entities.properties` is at the root, you want `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/entities.properties")` or `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("entities.properties")`

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes! getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("entities.properties") worked! I'll be happy to accept your answer if you "answer" it not in a comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the classloader used to load the class, not the context classloader.

Then, you have two options to get at a resource at the root of the jar file:

- Use `Class.getResourceAsStream`, passing in an absolute path (leading `/`)
- Use `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`, passing in a relative path (just `"entities.properties"`)

So either of:

```
InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/entities.properties");
InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("entities.properties");
```

Personally I'd use the first option as it's briefer and just as clear.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("entities.properties")
```

Comment: yes, It is true. Since Jon answered the same few minutes before via the comments section I promised him to accept his answer once he "answers" my question like you did. If he won't do it soon, I will accept yours gladly :) Thank you!